# Removing grid between transparent ggplot plots arranged by ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to produce a figure containing multiple `ggplot2` plots arranged by `ggarrange` from the package `ggpubr` and annotated on the left side. The `ggplot2` plots are transparent or have a transparent background.

The issue arose lately (i.e. I did not confront it this year earlier) where a light grey line appears between the plots and the annotation text on the left side as shown in the image below. And it is more prominent when the figure is inserted in LaTeX.

I tried to play with the individual plots, but there is no `plot.border` only `panel.border`, thus, all my trials were not successful!

**My maschine information**:

R 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

ggplot2 3.3.5

ggpubr 0.4.0

[image: 11111111111]

The code I used to produce it (and was inspired by [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/)):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Box plot (bp)
bxp <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
                                 color = "dose", palette = "jco")+
    
    theme_bw(base_size = 8)+
    
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
                legend.title = element_blank(),
                legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
                legend.background = element_blank(),
                legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black",fill=NA, 
                                                                                         size=0.1, linetype="solid"),
                legend.key.width = unit(5, "mm"),
                legend.spacing =  unit(1, 'mm'),
                legend.key.size  = unit(0.5, "mm"),
                legend.margin = margin(3,1,3,1, unit = "mm"))+
    
    theme(panel.grid.major =element_line(colour = "black",linetype = "dotted",size = 0.05), 
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                plot.margin = margin( 2.25,4.5,2.25,1, unit = "mm"),
                plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(1,0,1,0, unit = "mm"),size = 10),
                axis.line = element_blank(),
                axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"), axis.title= element_blank(),
                panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size=0.75),
                panel.background = element_rect(color = NA),
                rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent") )+ # all rectangles
    
    labs(title = expression("(a)"))+
    theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"))


# Dot plot (dp)
dp <- ggdotplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
                                color = "dose", palette = "jco", binwidth = 1)+
    
    theme_bw(base_size = 8)+
    
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
                legend.title = element_blank(),
                legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
                legend.background = element_blank(),
                legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black",fill=NA, 
                                                                                         size=0.1, linetype="solid"),
                legend.key.width = unit(5, "mm"),
                legend.spacing =  unit(1, 'mm'),
                legend.key.size  = unit(0.5, "mm"),
                legend.margin = margin(3,1,3,1, unit = "mm"))+
    
    theme(panel.grid.major =element_line(colour = "black",linetype = "dotted",size = 0.05), 
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                plot.margin = margin( 2.25,4.5,2.25,1, unit = "mm"),
                plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(1,0,1,0, unit = "mm"),size = 10),
                axis.line = element_blank(),
                axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"), axis.title= element_blank(),
                panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size=0.75),
                panel.background = element_rect(color = NA),
                rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent") )+ # all rectangles
    
    labs(title = expression("(b)"))+
    theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"))

bxp1<-bxp+labs(title = expression("(c)"))

dp1<-dp+labs(title = expression("(d)"))

figure <- ggarrange(bxp,bxp1,dp,dp1,
ncol = 2, nrow = 2,align = c("hv"))

figure <-annotate_figure(figure,left = text_grob("left side ",
color = "black",size = 10,  rot = 90))


ggsave(plot = figure, 
             filename = paste0("question.png"),
             height = 180, width =180, units = "mm", dpi = 300, device = "png",limitsize = FALSE)
```

**Edit**:

I can forget about the transparency by removeing `rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent")` ,however, the light grey gridline appears between the arragned plots and the antonatioed text of the left side.

The question can be: How to change the background of `textgrob()` to white instaed of transparent?

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine!

Comment: I can reproduce this, R 4.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Nitpick: `c("hv")` and `"hv"` and `paste0("question.png")` and `"question.png"` are exactly the same. And if you have `paste0` because in the real use case you have to assemble the output filename from a directory path and a filename, use `file.path`, not `paste0`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for the tips and for the reminder to add the machine/packages information:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with transparent arranged plots still exists. However, a progressive solution can be:

1. Producing ggplot2 plots with a white background by removing `rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent")` .
2. Using another approach to annotate and arrange plots:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gridtext)

yleft <- textGrob("left side", 
            rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10, fill= "white",color="black"))

figure <- grid.arrange(bxp,bxp1,
          dp,dp1,
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
          left=yleft)
```

**Update (March 2022):**
using the approach in the question and changing the background `bg` to white.

```
ggsave(plot = figure,
       filename = paste0("question.png"),
       height = 180, width =180, units = "mm", dpi = 300,
       device = "png",limitsize = FALSE,bg="white")
```

[image]